# Beautiful Soup 4: Getting certain attributes from a class

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I apologize in advance for any errors in terminology. I only have a very rudimentary knowledge of HTML, so I can't promise I will refer to everything correctly.

Anyways, I am writing a program in Python to automatically upload grades for students in a class I teach. On the website where I upload the grades, there are input slots for each student, with associated HTML that looks like this:

```
<div class="input text">
<label for="Grade0Value">Student Name</label>
<input name="data[Grade][0][value]" type="text" maxlength="11" value="10" 
id="Grade0Value"></div>
```

So far, I've managed to get some of the information I need like this:

```
ids = []
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for student in soup.find_all('label'):
    ids.append(student)
```

which returns:

```
[<label for="Grade0Value">Student Name</label>, . . . ]
```

from this, I need 2 things: the student's name ('Student Name'), which I have gotten by using

```
student.string
```

and the "Grade0Value". This is what I can't figure out. What 'attribute' (if that's the right word) do I need to get to return the id (where it says 'label for= ') for each student? Can I do it using a similar method to what I used to get the student's name?

Comment: You can specify attrs to get particular elements in beautiful soup

Comment: What are some examples of ones I should try? I've tried a few randomly, but I don't know very many, and none of the ones I've tested have worked.

Comment: Refer the documentation https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: Ah, I see now. I didn't know that you needed to refer to attributes like keys in a dictionary. I see now. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, self learning is the best learning

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<div class="input text">
<label for="Grade0Value">Student Name</label>
<input name="data[Grade][0][value]" type="text" maxlength="11" value="10" 
id="Grade0Value"></div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")
ids = []
label_fors = []

for student in soup.find_all('label'):
    ids.append(student.text)
    label_fors.append(student.get('for'))

print(ids)
print(label_fors)
```

And this code will return

```
['Student Name']
['Grade0Value']
```